# pgfplots varying vertical spacing in groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I think the title is self-explanatory, however:

I am trying to do a 2 by 3 groupplot (2 columns, 3 rows), but I want the spacing between rows 2 and 3 to be greater than between rows 1 and 2. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `yshift=<length>` to all the `\nextgroupplot`s on a specific row. For example:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=2 by 3,
    vertical sep=0cm,
    x descriptions at=edge bottom
  },
  height=3cm,width=5cm
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot{rnd};

\nextgroupplot
\addplot{rnd};


\nextgroupplot[yshift=-1cm]
\addplot{rnd};

\nextgroupplot[yshift=-1cm]
\addplot{rnd};

\nextgroupplot
\addplot{rnd};

\nextgroupplot
\addplot{rnd};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```